# macOS Catalina kernel panic while closing the Mac

Tags: macos, catalina, kernel-panic

After updating Mac to Catalina I got this kind of message when I want to close my Mac. How can remove this problem?

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f90c3faae): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 187 seconds (34 totalcheckins since monitoring last enabled), shutdown in progress
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81feaebc40 : 0xffffff800fb3bb1b 
0xffffff81feaebc90 : 0xffffff800fc733e5 
0xffffff81feaebcd0 : 0xffffff800fc64e5e 
0xffffff81feaebd20 : 0xffffff800fae2a40 
0xffffff81feaebd40 : 0xffffff800fb3b207 
0xffffff81feaebe40 : 0xffffff800fb3b5eb 
0xffffff81feaebe90 : 0xffffff80102d2575 
0xffffff81feaebf00 : 0xffffff7f90c3faae 
0xffffff81feaebf10 : 0xffffff7f90c3f472 
0xffffff81feaebf50 : 0xffffff7f90c54e76 
0xffffff81feaebfa0 : 0xffffff800fae213e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[EFAA17B9-A62C-30B7-9602-0BB5282EDDD6]@0xffffff7f90c3e000->0xffffff7f90c46fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[CA7CACA5-58A6-3E59-9F67-2422183AB544]@0xffffff7f90c47000->0xffffff7f90c65fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[3467C105-9354-3BD2-85F3-E5AEF94BD275]@0xffffff7f90c35000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[EFAA17B9-A62C-30B7-9602-0BB5282EDDD6]@0xffffff7f90c3e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1286D5E5-A6A1-3C44-A244-04C068903DB2]@0xffffff7f9052f000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19C57

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel slide:     0x000000000f800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800fa00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800f900000
System model name: MacBookPro14,1 (Mac-B4831CEBD52A0C4C)
System shutdown begun: YES
Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002cd)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 510691115259
last loaded kext at 110528277400: @filesystems.smbfs    3.4 (addr 0xffffff7f92752000, size 450560)
last unloaded kext at 187736978238: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f91234000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.1
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.3
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f4
>eficheck   1
>!ABacklight    180.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!A!IKBLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.3
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.61.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3420.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f4
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f4
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  569.3
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
|IOGraphics!F   569.3
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AActuatorDriver   3420.2
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3420.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f4
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f4
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f4
>!AMultitouchDriver 3420.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   58
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!AHSSPISupport 58
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.1
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.7
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: By closing you mean closing the lid or shutdown ? @safi